# Are there any sequences where the next term is calculated based on its own properties?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a "case"-based sequence, such as the [Collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem) sequence:

$$a_0 = n \\
a_{k+1} = \begin{cases}
f(a_k), & \text{if } a_k \text{ has property } p \\
g(a_k), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Des there exist a sequence where, instead of testing if $a_k$ has a property $p$, we test instead if $a_{k+1}$ has property $p$, or:

$$a_0 = n \\
a_{k+1} = \begin{cases}
f(a_k), & \text{if } a_{k+1} \text{ has property } p \\
g(a_k), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

It appears as though a lot of these sequences "fail" for specific numbers. For example, if we take a modified Collatz sequence:

$$a_0 = 2 \\
a_{k+1} = \begin{cases}
3a_k+1, & \text{if } a_{k+1} \text{ is odd} \\
a_k \div 2, & \text{if } a_{k+1} \text{ is even}
\end{cases}
$$

If we calculate both possible terms for $a_1$, we get $a_1 = 7$ and $a_1 = 1$. Therefore, $a_1$ will always be odd, so we can say that $a_1 = 7$. However, applying this again and we get a problem: $a_2 = 22$ or $a_2 = 3.5$. Unlike $a_1$, these cases don't both result in the same value, so we can't calculate $a_2$

---

Therefore, is there a non-trivial sequence $a_n$, with a property $p$ and a starting value $x$, such that

$$a_0 = x \\
a_{k+1} = \begin{cases}
f(a_k), & \text{if } a_{k+1} \text{ has property } p \\
g(a_k), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

is well-defined and determinable for all $a_n$? And, if so, is there a way to construct such sequences?

The values in the sequence do not have to be integers, and $x$ can be any value.

Comment: I don't see why you can't define a sequence that way.  e.g. the kth Fibonacci number $F_k = F_{k+2}- F_{k+1}$  However, it is not so convenient as it doesn't tell you where to start.  But, there is no reason for there to be any obvious relation between the $k^{th}$ and $(k+1)^{th}$ member of a sequence.  Consider the sequence $3,1,4,5,\cdots$ with each member of the sequence as the next number in the decimal representation of $\pi.$  It is a perfectly valid sequence, but it would be impossible to define a rule for any member based on the other members.

Comment: @DougM Obviously it's possible to define an arbitrary sequence where the next element is based on "future elements" like that. This is asking about sequences where the value of the next element is *dependent* on a property of itself, such as its parity

Comment: Notice that "case-based sequence" is just a convenient preference of notation. For example, instead of writing "if x is odd then $a$ else $b$" we can write "$a\cdot (x \bmod 2)+b\cdot (1-(x \bmod 2))$". So you are essentially asking for non-trivial sequences defined as $a_{k+1}=h(a_k,a_{k+1})$ ? Or are you specifically interested in $h=f(a_k) \text{ if } a_{k+1} \text{ satisfies } p \text{ else } g(a_k)$ ?

Comment: @Vepir The latter, I believe, (assuming $h$ calculates the next term in the sequence $a_{k+1}$)

Comment: Well, for instance, if $p$ is just the parity (even or odd), then $f$ and $g$ must have the same parity for same inputs. Otherwise, either both or neither of the two cases, will be satisfied. Then, e.g. $f(a)=a+1$, $g(a)=a+3$, $p=\text{ "is even" }$ works as an example for you? This will produce ($a(1)=1$) the sequence $1,2,5,6,9,10,13,\dots$ (*"Numbers congruent to 1 or 2 mod 4."*)

Comment: Hence, since you have only two cases, $f$ and $g$ must be such that $f(a),g(a)$ simultaneously satisfy (don't satisfy) property $p$ for all $a$. Is this something like the characterization you were looking for?